# how to insert a layout in layout2?

Tags: android

I have created 3 layout (Principal,Hor and Ver), I need to insert layoutVer into layoutHor, and then layoutHor into layoutPrincipal

```
    layoutVer.addView(TVTitulo,layoutParamsTitulo);
    layoutVer.addView(btVer,layoutParamsBoton);
    layoutHor.addView(Img,layoutParamsImagen);
    layoutHor.addView(layoutVer,layoutParamsVertical);
    layoutPrincipal.addView(layoutHor,layoutParamsHorizontal);
    layoutPrincipal.addView(separador,layoutParamsSeparador);
```

this block throws me the next error

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call 
    removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the views you are adding to another view (so either `separador`, `layoutHor`, `layoutVer`, `Img`, `btVer`, `TVTitulo`)

Has already been added to a view somewhere else.

So it already has a parent according to this error.

From what I can see, all of the views shown are only added to a parent view once. So that code looks fine.

Some other code must be adding one of the views to another parent.

For example if you tried to add your Img view to muliple parents you would get the same error:

```
layoutVer.addView(Img,layoutParamsBoton);
layoutHor.addView(Img,layoutParamsImagen);
```

In this example, you would be trying to give `Img` more than one parent.